# Why Static route (AD=150) and EIGRP route coexist under "show ip route"?

Tags: routing, eigrp

[image]

pic1 is topology
[image]

pic2 is routing table. EIGRP is enabled with auto summary, why there is a static router (AD=150)?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

The two routes are there because they are different routes.

172.16.0.0/16 and 172.16.10.0/24 are different routes with different mask lengths, so they are both put in the routing table.

Summarization only applies to routes the router advertises to other routers, not routes in its own table.

Comment: Hi Ron. Do you mean in R3 when EIGRP enabled with auto summary, 172.16.10.0 will be summarized to 172.16.0.0/16? And before eigrp the admin also configured a static route 172.16.10.0/24. So different routes put in table.